# Javascript passing variables to timeout function

Tags: javascript, timeout, vue.js

I'm trying to set a value after a amount of time.

For some reason I can't access the variable when in the function

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('hello');
    this.list[this.listIndex].glamour.show = true;           
}, 1000);
```

I'm inside a VueJS method and I'm trying to access properties of a VueJS template.

Comment: The value of `this` in that function won't be the same as it was in the surrounding code when the timer eventually fires. You can save `this` in another local variable outside the timer function and then use that variable instead of `this`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a variable that refers to the current object:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('hello');
  self.list[self.listIndex].glamour.show = true;
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the object from which you call the function. By default it's set to the window object.

```
function sayHello () {
    alert("Hello, I'm " + this.nickname + ".");
}
```

```
function make (nickname) {
    return {
        nickname: nickname,
        sayHello: sayHello
    };
}
```

```
bob = make("Bob");
jim = make("Jim");
nickname = "Window";
```

```
bob.sayHello(); /////////////// alerts "Hello, I'm Bob."
jim.sayHello(); /////////////// alerts "Hello, I'm Jim."
sayHello(); /////////////////// alerts "Hello, I'm Window."
window.sayHello(); //////////// alerts "Hello, I'm Window."
setTimeout(sayHello, 0); ////// alerts "Hello, I'm Window."
setTimeout(bob.sayHello, 0); // alerts "Hello, I'm Window."
```

To get around this behaviour you have at least 2 possibilities:

```
// a closure
setTimeout(function () { bob.sayHello(); }, 0);
```

```
// the .bind() method
setTimeout(sayHello.bind(bob), 0);
```